# White foam-ish residue on brakes: is it something to worry about?

Tags: honda, brakes, jazz

I have noticed white residue — a bit like some foam that would have dried up — on my 2016 Honda Jazz brakes:

[image]

It appears on the top and bottom of all four brakes. I haven't seen something similar on those of cars parked nearby. I haven't noticed any particular noise.

For context, tyres have been changed 2 months ago and I haven't driven since except for a 200 miles trip in winter (but no snow) conditions.

**What could be the cause of these? Is this something I should worry about?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears to me it is just the residue from a poorly applied amount of brake lube. The stuff they put on contact points of brake pads and slides to ensure it will continue to move throughout its life. It's nothing to worry about. You could even clean the wheel and brakes and most all of the exterior goop would go away. The stuff which you see isn't needed to perform the job it's there to do.